# Drag&Drop API Glitch while moving a row inside its cells

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

I am facing an issue with a table I have created. Each row in the table consists of three `<td>` elements. I have implemented the `onDragOver` event on each row, allowing the application of a custom CSS style to the currently dragged over row. However, when I attempt to move the row within itself, specifically from one table cell to another, I encounter glitches. The applied styles intermittently disappear and reappear. I am unable to comprehend the cause of this problem.

In an attempt to address the issue, I experimented with adding an event handler to the `<td>` elements to prevent the state from changing. Unfortunately, this approach did not yield the desired results. Furthermore, I experimented with adding a transparent background to each row using the `::after` pseudo-element, but this exacerbated the problem instead.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to rectify this issue.

## TableRow.tsx

```js
interface TableRowProps {
  id: number;
  handleDrop: (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => void;
}

export default function TableRow({ id, handleDrop }: TableRowProps) {
  const [isDraggedOver, setDraggedOver] = useState(false);

  const handleDragStart = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('taskId', id.toString());
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDraggedOver(true);
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => {
    setTimeout(() => setDraggedOver(false), 200);
  };

  const onDrop = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => {
    setDraggedOver(false);
    handleDrop(e);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <tr
        className={isDraggedOver ? styles.upper : ''}
        draggable={true}
        onDrop={onDrop}
        onDragOver={handleDragOver}
        onDragStart={handleDragStart}
        onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}>
        <td>Task {id}</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Anohter</td>
      </tr>
    </>
  );
}
```

## table-row.module.scss

```css
.upper {
  position: relative;

  &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    pointer-events: none;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```